# How to enable Text selection in Ionic webview

Tags: angularjs, cordova, webview, ionic-framework

Is there any way to enable text selection on an Ionic webview?

[image]

Use case: We show the user a news article rendered using in the app using the standard WebView. We want to give the user the ability to copy a selection of text from the screen, by press and holding the screen to show the text selection options...however this action is not available.

When using the InAppBrowser to show the same content, the text is selectable. But for other reasons, the InAppBrowser is not suitable for our requirements.

Comment: By default ionic has been disable the text-selection feature. We can do this by hacking the ionic code.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding

```
body {
 -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
.scroll {
    -webkit-user-select: inherit;
  }
}
```

to your CSS.